# How to color jitter by category in ggboxplot

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse, ggpubr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(feat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "KyteDoo", "FoldIndex"
), class = "factor"), dose = c("0.3mM", "1mM", "3mM", "10mM", 
"20mM", "0.3mM", "1mM", "3mM", "10mM", "20mM", "0.3mM", "1mM", 
"3mM", "10mM", "20mM"), vimp = c(-0.0025, 0, 0.0328571428571429, 
0.025, 0.0425, 0.005, 0.015, 0.0228571428571429, 0.0175, 0.02, 
0.0125, 0.01, 0.02, 0.0325, 0.015)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

It looks like this:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   feat      dose     vimp
   <fct>     <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A         0.3mM -0.0025
 2 A         1mM    0     
 3 A         3mM    0.0329
 4 A         10mM   0.025 
 5 A         20mM   0.0425
 6 KyteDoo   0.3mM  0.005 
 7 KyteDoo   1mM    0.015 
 8 KyteDoo   3mM    0.0229
 9 KyteDoo   10mM   0.0175
10 KyteDoo   20mM   0.02  
11 FoldIndex 0.3mM  0.0125
12 FoldIndex 1mM    0.01  
13 FoldIndex 3mM    0.02  
14 FoldIndex 10mM   0.0325
15 FoldIndex 20mM   0.015
```

And with this code:

```
 library(ggpubr)
 p <- ggboxplot(dat, x = "feat", y = "vimp",  add = "jitter") + 
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12))  + 
 xlab("") + 
 ylab("Variable Importance")
```

I can get this plot:

[image]

What I want to do is to color each dot in the jitter based on `dose` category.
I tried this but failed

```
 ggboxplot(dat, x = "feat", y = "vimp",  add = "jitter", color = "dose")
```

[image]

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to add the jittered points via a `geom_jitter` layer:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

ggboxplot(dat, x = "feat", y = "vimp") +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = dose)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Variable Importance")
```

[image]